# A sumset inequality

Tags: inequalities, additive-combinatorics, sumsets

A friend asked me the following problem:

> Is it true that for every $X\subset A\subset \mathbb{Z}$, where $A$ is finite and $X$ is non-empty, that $$\frac{|A+X|}{|X|}\geq \frac{|A+A|}{|A|}?$$

Here the notation $A+B$ denotes the set $\{ a+b\ : a\in A, b\in B\}$. 
It follows from Rusza's triangle inequality that $$\frac{|A+X|}{|X|}\geq \frac{|A+A|}{|A-X|},$$ but since $|A-X|\geq |A|$, this isn't quite strong enough.

It is not hard to show that the inequality holds in either of the extremal cases where $A+A$ is minimal or maximal - that is when $|A+A|=|A|(|A|+1)/2$ or $|A+A|=2|A|-1$.

Is this statement true in general?

Rewriting the desired inequality as $$\frac{|A+X|}{|A+A|}\geq \frac{|X|}{|A|},$$ we are asking if adding $A$ to $X$ and looking at this as a subset of $A+A$ causes the proportion of elements to increase.

**Edit: Numerical Calculations:**

I did some numerical calculations where I let $A$ run through all possible subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ and $X$ run through all proper subsets of $A$, and I calculated the ratio $$\frac{|A+X||A|}{|A+A||X|}.$$  The minimum of this ratio over all possible combinations of $A,X$ with $X\subsetneq A\subset\{1,2,3\dots,n\}$ appears in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{value of }n\ \  & \text{minimum}\\
3 & 4/3\\
4 & 6/5\\
5 & 8/7\\
6 & 10/9\\
7 & 12/11\\
8 & 14/13\\
9 & 16/15\\
10 & 18/17
\end{array} $$ Numerically the slightly stronger estimate $$\frac{|A+X|}{|A+A|}\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{2|X|+1}\right)\frac{|X|}{|A|}$$ seems to hold.

Comment: If X is an A-basis (so that A+X=A+A), the inequality then holds for all subsets Y of A containing X.  It strikes me that maximal subsets of minimal A-bases are a good case to analyze.  I vote that the inequality does hold.

Comment: Have you tried to verify computationally your inequality for all pairs $(A,X)$ with, say, $A\subset[1,10]$?

Comment: Have you counterexamples in additive groups other than $\mathbb Z$, in non-abelian groups (replacing $A+X$ and $A+A$ by $AX$ and $A^2$?

Comment: @Seva I wrote a program which chooses $A$ as a random subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $X$ as a random subset of $A$, and for $1$ million trials with $n=100$, the inequality always holds. I'll write a program that checks all subsets of $\{1,\dots,10\}$ and all possibilities $X$ and test it.

Comment: well, with high probability random set is Sidon, so it is not surprising  that the inequality holds. Have you tried looking at the extremal examples in Feiman 3n-3 theorem?

Comment: @Alvin, Seva: I checked all possible combinations $X\subsetneq A\subset \{1,2,3\dots, 10\}$ and the inequality always holds. I edit the question to this in.

Comment: Your computations seem to suggest that equality holds if and only if $X=A$? By the way, do you have a counterexample in a small cyclic group? I have the impression (without error of my part) that the inequality holds for $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ with $N=2,3,4$.

Comment: Is actually the slightly more general: $F(B) := |A+B|/|B|$ is monotonically $\downarrow$ worth asking about?

Comment: @Eric Is it worth allowing sets that include non-positive integers for your numerical tests?

Comment: @Carl: You can translate $X$ and $A$ by the same amount, this translates sums by the double amount but does not change cardinalities of the sets. It is thus enough to assume that $A$ starts with $0$.

Comment: For $A\subset B+C$, the following inequality seems to hold $\displaystyle\frac{|A+A|}{|A|} \le \frac{|A+B||A+C|}{|A+A|}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proposed inequality is not true. I do not claim originality for this example: all I have done is take Seva's observation that the inequality would imply an improvement $|3A|\leq K^2|A|$ given $|2A|\leq K|A|$, find a standard counterexample to this hypothetical improvement, and then simplify it a bit for the present situation.

I will work inside in $\mathbf{Z}^2$, but this makes no difference because one can always just look at the image in $\mathbf{Z}$ under $(x,y)\mapsto x + My$ for large $M$.

Let $X = [x]^2$ and
$$A = X \cup \{(j,0): j\in [Kx]\}\cup\{(0,j): j\in [Kx]\}.$$
Then for $x$ large enough $|A+X|/|X|\approx 2K$ and $|A+A|/|A|\approx K^2$.

One can get something from Petridis's results though, namely that if $X\subset A$ and $|A+X|\leq K|X|$ then $|A+A|\leq K^2|A|$.

Comment: Great! This is what I was thinking of, but couldn't recall where I saw a counterexample to $|3A|\le K^2|A|$. Is there any standard reference for this?

Comment: @Seva There must be but I don't know it. I found the example on one of Ben Green's examples sheets from his additive combinatorics course in Cambridge, but I think even that is no longer on the web. Maybe there is something similar in Tao and Vu, but I haven't checked thoroughly.

Comment: For the record the counterexample to $|3A|\leq K^2|A|$ was actually the following: Work inside $\mathbf{Z}^3$ and let $X=[x]^3$ and $A=X\cup\{(j,0,0):j\in[Kx]\}\cup\cdots$. Now $|2A|\lesssim K|A|$ but $|3A|\gtrsim K^3|A|$.

Comment: I am not getting $|A+A|/|A|$ as anything near $K^2$ for the example, and suspect a typo.  Can someone fix it or explain? (When the numerics make sense to me, I'll believe in it as a counterexample.)  Gerhard "Likes Examples With Sensible Numerics" Paseman, 2014.03.14

Comment: @GerhardPaseman $A+A$ contains all $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i,j\leq Kx$, so certainly $|A+A|\geq K^2 x^2$. On the other hand $|A|\leq x^2 + 2Kx$. Now take $x$ large.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, thanks, I was confusing myself with x's and K's.  Gerhard "Minding My P's And Q's" Paseman, 2014.03.14

Comment: I believe Ruzsa's survey article http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-2418-1_21 should contain a similar counterexample, though I can't access it currently.  (The existence of such a counterexample is Exercise 2.4.9 of my book with Van, but we didn't give a hint.)

Answer (score 7):

In particular for $x = 5$, $K = 5$ and $M = 22$ in Sean Eberhard's example, the inequality is violated (assuming $[x]$ means $\lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots, x \rbrace$).

I get $X = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,22,23,24,25,26,27,44,45,46,47,48,49,66,67,68,69,70,71,88,89,90,91,92
      ,93,110,111,112,113,114,115\}$

$A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,44,45,
 46,47,48,49,66,67,68,69,70,71,88,89,90,91,92,93,110,111,112,113,114,115,132,154,176,198,220,242,264,286,308,330,352,374,396,418,440,462,484,506,528,
      550\}$

and $|X| = 36$,
$|A| = 72$,
$|A+X| = 307$,
$|A+A| = 622$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very incomplete answer at this stage, but it establishes some connections worth recording.

A well-known [lemma by Petridis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2532) says that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, non-empty subsets of an abelian group such that $|X+B|/|X|\ge|A+B|/|A|$ holds for every non-empty subset $X\subset A$, then for every finite set $C$ one has $|A+B+C||A|\le|A+B||A+C|$. Your inequality (if true) says that the assumption of Petridis' lemma always holds true in the situation where $B=A$ and the underlying group is the group of integers. As a result, 
  $$ |2A+C||A|\le|2A||A+C| $$
for any finite integer sets $A$ and $C$. Letting here $C=(n-2)A$ with integer $n\ge 3$, we conclude that if $|2A|=K|A|$, then $|nA|\le K^{n-1}|A|$. The "standard" estimate here is $K^n|A|$, and I doubt it can be improved to $K^{n-1}|A|$ - though, maybe, the integer case is special in this respect.